# Авторизация через Mail.ru на Node.js (OAuth)

Tags: node.js, mail.ru, post, авторизация, https

В инструкции написано

Не получается отправить https POST запрос.

Обменяйте полученный авторизационный код на идентификатор сессии, который вы сможете использовать для доступа к REST API. Для этого с сервера сделайте следующий POST-вызов на адрес https://connect.mail.ru/oauth/token:

```
POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.1
Host: connect.mail.ru
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 186
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=464119&
client_secret=ac7fd2cc742c70a707cad3f6b2ca1c89&
grant_type=authorization_code&
code=000ff8627d2d79b60ebdaf004f9a68aa&
redirect_uri=http://example.com/oauth/receiver
```

Вот это "POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.1" вообще как отправлять, куды приклеить то?

Заварил такую кашу но пока безуспешно

```
var content="";
var post_data = querystring.stringify({
    "client_id":id,
    "client_secret":secret,
    "grant_type":"authorization_code",
    "code":req.query['code'],
    "redirect_uri":redir
});
var options = {
    hostname: 'connect.mail.ru',
    path: "/oauth/token",
    method: 'POST',
    headers:
    {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Length':post_data.length,
        'Accept': '*/*'
    }
};
b="";
var reqq = https.request(options, function(res) {
    console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
    console.log("headers: ", res.headers);

    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function(d) {
        b+=b;
    });

    res.on('end', function() {
        console.log(b);
    });
});

reqq.write(post_data);
reqq.end();
```

Если кто сталкивался подкиньте примерчик

Comment: Если ответ правильный, отметьте, пожалуйста, его галочкой "принят"

Comment: На тот момент не нашел модуля для Маил.ру. Да и для Одноклассников почему-то не работал. В итоге реализации для них написал сам.

Answer (score 1):

Для авторизации в Node.js есть библиотека [Passport](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport) и она имеет модуль [Mail.ru](https://github.com/tiberule/passport-mailru)

Comment: На тот момент модуля для маил.ру не нашел. И для "одноклассников" не рабочий был. Все остальные "соцсети" через "Passport" сделал, а эти два сам написал.